# State of STM32 pins from factory and after chip erase

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, memory, pins, reset

What is the state of pins for an STM32 MCU after chip erase or when the device is fresh from factory?

I'm asking in search of a controlled way to power up and test a new board with STM32.

Comment: Normally, at reset most of the pins are in hi-Z state. Upon release from reset, the programmed firmware (or bootloader, if any and activated) can change them to be an output. After an erase, there is no firmware, but there can be a bootloader. Often the bootloader activates itself if a particular connection is found on some of the pin - you must check the datasheet.

Comment: The state ought to be as foretold in the friendly manual. Did you try to read it? Was there some specific part you didn't understand?

Comment: I tried looking in the datasheet and reference manual but didn't find an applicable section. Could you advice what section this information can be found under?

Comment: Reference Manual, the GPIO Register description. And the application note AN2606 for information on the Bootloader.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515999/stm32-unwanted-bootloader-on-first-power-up here is more on the bootloader thing. It can bite you.

Comment: It seems like a can of worms.. I feel it is much easier to configure the pins manually, as this would take much less time than reading about each register setting.

Comment: Well you're not really going to get around that if you want to understand what your system is doing everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the registers are in know reset state during and after reset before software configures them. That state is available for all registers, and can be found in the Reference Manual.

After reset the pins should be set to analog inputs so that will be the state if nothing changes the IO pins.

The bootloader will configure all the pins for all the interfaces it supports so if you start the bootloader, some pins will become outputs, and for example UART pins will be high outputs. It also means some pins will become inputs that must be in a known state or at least not toggling so the bootloader can determine which interface to use based on activity on e.g. UART input pins.

What pins are used is basically dependent on which exact MCU model you have and there is an appnote for that.

Comment: By "should be set to analog inputs", do you mean by user or automatically by default?

Comment: @NoobPointerException by default (reset value of the register), but there are some exceptions like the Serial Wire Debug pins.